# jquery function to big

Tags: javascript, jquery

we make jquery function for map section which is coming on my website but it is too big can any one make this code in small using var and other thing  function we make jquery function for map section which is coming on my website but it is too big can any one make this code in small using var and other thing  function:-

Please check code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#foot-map #uktabfoot").click(function(){
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-address').find('.uk-address').show();
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-address').find('.malta-address').hide();
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-address').find('.india-address').hide();

    // map section tab
    $('#foot-map').find('.maplink').find('#uktabfoot').addClass('active');
    $('#foot-map').find('.maplink').find('#maltatabfoot').removeClass('active');
    $('#foot-map').find('.maplink').find('#indiatabfoot').removeClass('active');

    // map section icon
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.uk').addClass('map-hover');
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.malta').removeClass('map-hover');
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.india').removeClass('map-hover');

    // map section flag
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.uk').find('.flag').css('display','block');
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.malta').find('.flag').css('display','none');
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.india').find('.flag').css('display','none');        
});
$("#foot-map #maltatabfoot").click(function(){
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-address').find('.uk-address').hide();
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-address').find('.malta-address').show();      
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-address').find('.india-address').hide();

    // map section tab
    $('#foot-map').find('.maplink').find('#uktabfoot').removeClass('active');
    $('#foot-map').find('.maplink').find('#maltatabfoot').addClass('active');
    $('#foot-map').find('.maplink').find('#indiatabfoot').removeClass('active');

    // map section
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.uk').removeClass('map-hover')
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.malta').addClass('map-hover');
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.india').removeClass('map-hover');

    // map section flag
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.uk').find('.flag').css('display','none');
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.malta').find('.flag').css('display','block');
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.india').find('.flag').css('display','none');        
});
$("#foot-map #indiatabfoot").click(function(){
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-address').find('.uk-address').hide();
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-address').find('.malta-address').hide();
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-address').find('.india-address').show();

    // map section tab
    $('#foot-map').find('.maplink').find('#uktabfoot').removeClass('active');
    $('#foot-map').find('.maplink').find('#maltatabfoot').removeClass('active');
    $('#foot-map').find('.maplink').find('#indiatabfoot').addClass('active');

    // map section
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.uk').removeClass('map-hover')
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.malta').removeClass('map-hover');
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.india').addClass('map-hover');

    // map section flag
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.uk').find('.flag').css('display','none');
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.malta').find('.flag').css('display','none');
    $('#foot-map').find('.map-area').find('.india').find('.flag').css('display','block');           
});
});
```

Comment: have you ever heard of full stops or capital letters? Your question is barely readable.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a drive-thru code review service. Does the code actually work?

Comment: Please don't repeat text just to get around the site limits.

Comment: Yes my code is working

Comment: @BharatNegi Then you should go away and study the jQuery documentation to learn how this could be written better. Try to minimize its footprint yourself, and come back here when you run into some problems.

Comment: As a quick pointer, `$('#foot-map').find('.maplink').find('#uktabfoot')` is FAR too verbose. You could just have `$('#uktabfoot')`, since your ID attributes should be unique in the DOM.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Rob is it valid for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps!!!

```
function getMapSection(findClass) {
    return $('#foot-map').find(findClass);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var _address = getMapSection('.map-address');
    var _mapLink = getMapSection('.maplink');
    var _mapArea = getMapSection('.map-area');

    $("#foot-map #uktabfoot").click(function () {
        $(_address).find('.uk-address').show();
        $(_address).find('.malta-address').hide();
        $(_address).find('.india-address').hide();

        // map section tab
        $(_mapLink).find('#uktabfoot').addClass('active');
        $(_mapLink).find('#maltatabfoot').removeClass('active');
        $(_mapLink).find('#indiatabfoot').removeClass('active');

        // map section icon
        $(_mapArea).find('.uk').addClass('map-hover');
        $(_mapArea).find('.malta').removeClass('map-hover');
        $(_mapArea).find('.india').removeClass('map-hover');

        // map section flag
        $(_mapArea).find('.uk').find('.flag').css('display', 'block');
        $(_mapArea).find('.malta').find('.flag').css('display', 'none');
        $(_mapArea).find('.india').find('.flag').css('display', 'none');
    });
    $("#foot-map #maltatabfoot").click(function () {
        $(_address).find('.uk-address').hide();
        $(_address).find('.malta-address').show();
        $(_address).find('.india-address').hide();

        // map section tab
        $(_mapLink).find('#uktabfoot').removeClass('active');
        $(_mapLink).find('#maltatabfoot').addClass('active');
        $(_mapLink).find('#indiatabfoot').removeClass('active');

        // map section
        $(_mapArea).find('.uk').removeClass('map-hover')
        $(_mapArea).find('.malta').addClass('map-hover');
        $(_mapArea).find('.india').removeClass('map-hover');

        // map section flag
        $(_mapArea).find('.uk').find('.flag').css('display', 'none');
        $(_mapArea).find('.malta').find('.flag').css('display', 'block');
        $(_mapArea).find('.india').find('.flag').css('display', 'none');
    });
    $("#foot-map #indiatabfoot").click(function () {
        $(_address).find('.uk-address').hide();
        $(_address).find('.malta-address').hide();
        $(_address).find('.india-address').show();

        // map section tab
        $(_mapLink).find('#uktabfoot').removeClass('active');
        $(_mapLink).find('#maltatabfoot').removeClass('active');
        $(_mapLink).find('#indiatabfoot').addClass('active');

        // map section
        $(_mapArea).find('.uk').removeClass('map-hover')
        $(_mapArea).find('.malta').removeClass('map-hover');
        $(_mapArea).find('.india').addClass('map-hover');

        // map section flag
        $(_mapArea).find('.uk').find('.flag').css('display', 'none');
        $(_mapArea).find('.malta').find('.flag').css('display', 'none');
        $(_mapArea).find('.india').find('.flag').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but we link most if you make this code small high wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make code more reusable:

Pointers:

- Keep approach consistent. You are doing `hide/show`, `add/remove` class and `display none/block`. Instead use a common approach for class.
- To manipulate class, you can use `$.toggleClass`. This expects second argument as boolean value. `true` will add, `false` will remove.
- Now write a function that satisfies conditions for all cases.

#### Sample:

```js
// Have a generic handler for all elements
$("#uktabfoot, #maltatabfoot, #indiatabfoot").click(function() {

  // Keep a copy of prefixes for all elements
  const idPrefix = ['uk', 'matla', 'india'];
  
  // this variable will be used to relate to current element
  var initial = "";
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < idPrefix.length; i++) {
    if (id.indexOf(idPrefix[i]) > -1) {
      // initialise based on ID of currrent element
      initial = idPrefix[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  // this will hold all validation code for relation
  function isRelatedToCurrent(selectorType, el, value) {
    switch (selectorType) {
      case "class": return $(el).hasClass(value)
      case "id": return $(el).attr(id) === value;
    }
  }

  $('#foot-map')
    .find('.map-address [class$="-address"]')
    .toggleClass("hide", !isRelatedToCurrent("class", this, initial + "-address"));

  // map section tab
  $('#foot-map')
    .find('.maplink [id$=tabfoot]')
    .toggleClass('active', isRelatedToCurrent('id', this, initial + 'tabfoot'));

  // map section icon
  var _classList = idPrefix.map(x => "." + x).join(" ");
  $('#foot-map')
    .find('.map-area ' + _classList)
    .toggleClass('map-hover', isRelatedToCurrent("class", this, initial))
    .toggleClass('hide', !isRelatedToCurrent("class", this, initial))
});
```